# 403 url rewrite error issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi guys I a major issue with url rewrite. Apologizes if you might have seen this somewhere before.

**issue here**

If i enter a url for example `exampl.x10.mx` OR `www.example.x10.mx` I get a 403 error which shouldnt happen because

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.x10.mx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is **MIGHT** to take care of that.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lwh/

RewriteCond $1 !^lwh/
```

The code above hiden the lwh folder.

FULL **.htaccess**  CODE

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lwh/
RewriteCond $1 !^lwh/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.x10.mx [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) /lwh/main/pages/general/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lwh/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Summary of the problem**
If i remember

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lwh/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lwh/$1 [L]
```

the code below works and the same happens if i remember the code below. The thing is I need both of them.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.x10.mx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

An idea why this is happening please

Comment: Can you write something about your actual requirements also like what are you trying to do.

Comment: @anubhava please looks at the **issue here**

Comment: Your link didn't get posted.

Comment: You wrote: `anubhava please looks at the` **issue here** I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: its not a link its in the question... look for **issue here** in the question

Comment: @anubhava I have also edited the question to add **Summary of the problem** please look in the question... Its adds a break down of the issue. Hopefully that explains it much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the 
R=301 (permanent redirect to new URL)

**Before**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**now**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your .htaccess with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.x10\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.x10.mx/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lwh/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.x10\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lwh/main/pages/general/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am having probelm with the url redirect and if u type `www.example.x10.mx`

Comment: Sorry, no matter how much I tried to decipher your problem its clear I'm no where close. Please state your problem clearly then I will make another attempt.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lwhitneyhair\.x10\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lwhitneyhair.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]` is not doing what it should do.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lwh/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.x10\.mx$ [NC]` is doing his job.

the problem is why isn't `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lwhitneyhair\.x10\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lwhitneyhair.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]` doing what it should so

Comment: yes I when back and read what it meant R=301 (permanent redirect to new URL)